# Cognos Report Studio Error Invalid to Compare Sets

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-10

I am using Cognos Report Studio in Cognos 10.2.2. I am trying to create conditional rendering by displaying text the same color as the background (for the purpose of not suppressing a crosstab space) when certain conditions are met. It apppears to work fine with one variable but when I start adding more I get the following error:

`Invalid to compare Sets in expression for a dataItem="Render Other Expenses".`

`CAF-WRN-2082 An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator. The complete error has been logged by CAF with SecureErrorID:2018-02-21-08:04:14.085-#92`

All of my variables are based on data items with the following structure:

```
IF( 
    ((completetuple([Item1],[ItemA],[Measure], CurrentMember([Heirarchy])) + 
     (completetuple([Item1],[ItemB],[Measure], CurrentMember([Heirarchy])))=0
THEN
    (0)
ELSE
    (1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!